# Send key to inactive window of process

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to create a simple program in C# which sends the SPACE key to an inactive window or process (Wow.exe). However, I have no knowledge of C# what so ever so if you want to try help me please do but if you can't be bothered explaining to a noob that's fine ;)

So basically the little program will be for the game World of Warcraft and will hopefully send a SPACE key to the game every 30 seconds and make the character jump. Preventing the character to automatically going away from keyboard.

It will be a single buttoned program which will start sending the SPACE key once you click the button and will stop when the program is closed. But, I want it to send the key to the game even if it isn't the current active window. So I can be watching a film on Netflix and have it doing it in the background.

What would I put inside this when the button is clicked?...

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

If it's going more complicated than inserting some code inside there just say and I won't bother trying to make it :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to grab the Window Handle ([Process.MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx)), and then [P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage) the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [virtual key code for space bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I'll have a read later and try getting it working. Thanks for the help. =)

Answer (score 0):

It is unable to send to inactive Window as for active just write Keys.Send("{SPACE}");or Keys.SendWait("{SPACE}");