# Fullscreen screenshot, but without my Program in the taken sreenshot

Tags: c#, wpf, image, process, jpeg

[This](http://postimg.org/image/uzvwdkbft/) is what I have so far.

"TheMovieScreenShotTaker" is right in the middle of the screenshot, I used to find two way to work around that problem:

1. Use a second screen and move my prgram to that extended screen, which is connecteced to my laptop(that works) and press the button from the second screen.
2. Use [AHK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013900/send-key-to-inactive-window-of-process), but this did not work.

This is the relevant code I use:

```
 System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(System.Drawing.Point.Empty, System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }

            string zwischen = pathCreator(name).Equals("empty") ? "" : pathCreator(name);

            if (zwischen.Equals("empty"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Erstellen des Ordners");
            }
            else
            {
                bitmap.Save(zwischen, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            }
        }
```

I am using a backgroundworker to achive this.

May be I can exclude my program from the picture, like using layers(gimp, photoshop) and take everything exept my program for the screenshot ?!

And I thought of something like this: register keystrokes somewhere in the system like if you press `strg+alt+delete` for the `taskmanager`, and than if the keystrok event raises it will load my "TheMovieScreenShotTaker"(or at least it will load the assembly `Assembly.LoadFile` and get+excecute my method, which will take the screenshot...

What do you think ?

Comment: That code is WinForms, not WPF.

Comment: I use that code snippet in WPF, based on this post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window".