# Use SendKeys with a non-active window

Tags: c#, window, sendkeys

Can I `SendKeys` to a selected window in c#?

The Program knows the window which it has to send it and the window not really necessary to be the active window.
I just want to give the program window name and send into it.

EX : I type  application name (notepad for example) and not really necessary to be focused Upon the meant window.

Comment: Elaborate on your idea. I can't quite get it. Is my assumption correct?  1. Record typing input on notepad 2. Select a window and using program to simulate keyboard input, where data is record in 1.?

Comment: @Louis OP is saying that they want to use SendKeys with a non-active window.

Comment: This sounds like a P/Invoke situation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013900/send-key-to-inactive-window-of-process
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339502/sendkeys-to-inactive-application might help.

Comment: @John sorry for the question actually i have already joined here